# Producer-Consumer multi threads syncing problems

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, synchronization

Hello All (first post)!

Let me first say I'm still relatively new to programming in Java (C++ is my strong point)

If this has already been answered please point me in the right direction, but my search skills have yet to yield what I am looking for. My problem I am running into is syncing between my consumer threads and not between my Producer/Consumer

My assignment consists of finding prime number candidates from the producer thread than using multiple consumer threads to check the validity of each candidate:

- Using multiple threads, 1 producer thread that puts 'candidates' into an arraylist (has to be arraylists) called *prime_candidates*, the consumers than grab from the arraylist and check
- Consumers check, if it is a prime, than they put the prime into their own arraylist *prime_list*
- After 60 seconds the *prime_list* is written to file and continues

I have successfully Synchronized the *prime_candidates* with the consumer (check) threads. But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to Sync the ArrayLists that the consumer threads produce. They all make their own and using the synchronized methods that I used from the Producer/Consumer doesn't work.

**PRODUCER THREAD**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class GenerateThread implements Runnable{

// MAIN ARRAY LIST THAT STORES THE NUMBERS WHICH COULD BE CONSIDERED PRIME CANDIDATES
private final ArrayList<PrimeCandidate> prime_candidates = new ArrayList();

private boolean alive = true;   // MAIN VARIABLE THAT WILL CONTINUE TO RUN THE THREAD 
private boolean toggle = true;  // VARIABLE THAT PAUSES THE PRODUCER

// START: FOR PANEL LAYOUT //
JPanel genPanel = new JPanel();

JPanel lastPane = new JPanel();
JLabel lastOutput = new JLabel();

JPanel queuePane = new JPanel();
JLabel queueOutput = new JLabel();

JLabel headLabel = new JLabel("Generate Thread");
JLabel lastLabel = new JLabel("Last");
JLabel queueLabel = new JLabel("Queue");

JButton pauseButton = new JButton("Pause");
JButton terminateButton = new JButton("Terminate");
// END: FOR PANEL LAYOUT //

// DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR, DOESN'T REALLY DO MUCH
GenerateThread(){ System.out.println("Creating Generator");}

public JPanel createPanel()
{
    // TO SET THE BLACK BORDER AROUND THE PANELS HOLDING CURRENT SIZE AND 
    // PRIME CANDIDATE
    lastPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    queuePane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

    // ADD LISTENER TO TERMINATE THREAD
    terminateButton.addActionListener(new terminateListener());

    // ADD LISTENER TO PAUSE THREAD
    pauseButton.addActionListener(new pauseListener());

    lastPane.add(lastOutput);
    queuePane.add(queueOutput);

    genPanel.add(headLabel);
    genPanel.add(lastLabel);
    genPanel.add(lastPane);
    genPanel.add(queueLabel);
    genPanel.add(queuePane);
    genPanel.add(pauseButton);
    genPanel.add(terminateButton);

    return genPanel;
}


@Override
public void run() 
{
    long i = 3;
    while(alive)
    {
        if(toggle)
        {
            if(i % 2 == 1)
                if(!TestForPrime.isDividableBy3(BigInteger.valueOf(i)))
                {
                    addToArrayList(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
                    lastOutput.setText(BigInteger.valueOf(i).toString());
                    queueOutput.setText(BigInteger.valueOf(prime_candidates.size()).toString());
                }
            i++;
        }
        if(!toggle)continueNotifying();
    }
    while(!alive){continueNotifying();}
}

// ADDS NEW ITEM TO ARRAYLIST AND NOTIFYS ALL THREADS DEPENDENT ON ARRAYLIST
public synchronized void addToArrayList(BigInteger b)
{
        prime_candidates.add(new PrimeCandidate(b, new Date()));
        notify();
}

// CONTINUES NOTIFYING OTHER THREADS WHEN PAUSED OR TERMINATED SINCE THEY WILL
// NOT RUN UNLESS THEY HAVE BEEN GIVEN THE 'GO AHEAD' (NOTIFY())
public synchronized void continueNotifying()
{
    queueOutput.setText(BigInteger.valueOf(prime_candidates.size()).toString());
    notify();
}

// USED BY THE OTHER THREADS TO GET ITEMS FROM THE ARRAY LIST, THREADS DELETE
// THE VARIABLE THAT THEY GRAB, ESSENTIALLY CUTTING THE ARRAY LIST DOWN EVERY
// TIME
public synchronized PrimeCandidate getFromArrayList() throws InterruptedException 
{
      wait(); //Keeps thread from adding more to list while others are grabbing it

      PrimeCandidate returnCandidate = new PrimeCandidate(prime_candidates.get(0));

      prime_candidates.remove(0);

      return returnCandidate;
}

// LISTENER THAT WILL KILL THE THREAD PRIME CANDIDATE PRODUCER
// ALSO GREYS OUT BOTH BUTTONS TO SHOW THREAD IS DEAD
class terminateListener implements ActionListener
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    { 
        terminateButton.setEnabled(false);
        pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
        alive = false;
    }
}

// LISTENER THAT WILL TEMPORARILY STOP THE PRODUCER
class pauseListener implements ActionListener
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    { 
        if(toggle)
            pauseButton.setText("Start");
        if(!toggle)
            pauseButton.setText("Pause");
        toggle = !toggle;
    }
}
}
```

**Consumer Thread**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;  
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class CheckThread  implements Runnable{

private final GenerateThread generated;
private ArrayList<Primes> prime_list = new ArrayList();
//private CopyOnWriteArrayList<Primes> prime_list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList();
private final String threadName;
private boolean alive = true;
private boolean toggle = true;
private Date timeFetched;
private Date timeFound;
private Primes currentPrime;

// START: FOR PANEL LAYOUT //
JPanel genPanel = new JPanel();

JPanel lastPane = new JPanel();
JLabel lastOutput = new JLabel();

JPanel queuePane = new JPanel();
JLabel queueOutput = new JLabel();

JLabel headLabel = new JLabel("Generate Thread");
JLabel lastLabel = new JLabel("Last");
JLabel queueLabel = new JLabel("In Work");

JButton pauseButton = new JButton("Pause");
JButton terminateButton = new JButton("Terminate");
// END: FOR PANEL LAYOUT //

CheckThread(GenerateThread gen, String name, int priority)
{
    generated = gen;
    threadName = name;
    headLabel.setText(name);
    System.out.println("Creating | " + name);

    if(priority == 0)
    {
       System.out.println(name + " Is writing thread");
        final Timer t = new Timer(10000, new writeToFileTimer());
        t.start();
    }
}

public JPanel createPanel()
{
   lastPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
   lastPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200,100));
   queuePane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));


   terminateButton.addActionListener(new terminateListener());

   pauseButton.addActionListener(new pauseListener());

   lastPane.add(lastOutput);
   queuePane.add(queueOutput);

   genPanel.add(headLabel);
   genPanel.add(lastLabel);
   genPanel.add(lastPane);
   genPanel.add(queueLabel);
   genPanel.add(queuePane);
   genPanel.add(pauseButton);
   genPanel.add(terminateButton);

   lastOutput.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
   return genPanel;
}
 class writeToFileTimer implements ActionListener
 {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
       try{ writeToFile();}catch (InterruptedException e) { System.out.println("WTF");}
    }
 }

@Override
public void run() 
{
    while(alive)
    {
        try 
        {
            if(toggle)
            {
                PrimeCandidate recieved = new PrimeCandidate(generated.getFromArrayList());
                timeFetched = new Date();
                //queueOutput.setText(recieved.getCandidate().toString());
                if(TestForPrime.isPrime(recieved.getCandidate()))
                {
                    lastOutput.setText(recieved.getCandidate().toString());
                    timeFound = new Date();
                    String temp = "" + prime_list.size();
                    queueOutput.setText(temp);
                    addToArrayList(new Primes(recieved.getCandidate(),recieved.getTimeStamp(), timeFetched));
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}

class terminateListener implements ActionListener
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    { 
        terminateButton.setEnabled(false);
        pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
        alive = false;
    }
}

class pauseListener implements ActionListener
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    { 
        if(toggle)
            pauseButton.setText("Start");
        if(!toggle)
            pauseButton.setText("Pause");
        toggle = !toggle;
    }
}

// ADDS NEW ITEM TO ARRAYLIST AND NOTIFYS ALL THREADS DEPENDENT ON ARRAYLIST 
public synchronized void addToArrayList(Primes primeFound)
{
        prime_list.add(primeFound);
}

// USED BY THE OTHER THREADS TO GET ITEMS FROM THE ARRAY LIST, THREADS DELETE
// THE VARIABLE THAT THEY GRAB, ESSENTIALLY CUTTING THE ARRAY LIST DOWN EVERY
// TIME
public synchronized void writeToFile() throws InterruptedException
{
    wait(); 
    try 
    {
        File statText = new File("prime_numbers.txt");

        FileOutputStream is = new FileOutputStream(statText);

        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(is);    

        Writer writ = new BufferedWriter(osw);
        while(!prime_list.isEmpty())
        {
            writ.append(prime_list.get(0).toString());
            prime_list.remove(0);
        }
        writ.close();
        headLabel.setText(threadName);

    } catch (IOException e) {System.err.println(" failed to write to Test.txt");}
    notify();
}   
}
```

I know the code is ill written but as I do this assignment I keep running into a wall and rewriting my code from scratch and have finally stopped caring. Does anyone know how I can easily sync all my prime_list Arraylist in the consumer threads. If you didn't notice I built each array list so I could simply add each thread/panel to the main frame. It works flawlessy in terms of getting and checking of the primes but my current headache is writing to a file what all the threads together have produced. I can write each thread individually to the file but they end up over writing each other everytime

Comment: What is your question? In one sentence please.

Comment: Welcome to the community. I'd suggest editing your question after reading through this: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: If you "have finally stopped caring" why do you expect anybody else to care?
More to the point:
you should phrase the question so it is understandable what you need help with and 
your code should be short and include only parts relevant to the problem you are asking about - in your case there is no need for any GUI code here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you need the accumulated prime numbers of all Consumers to be written to a file every 60 second.

For now you are using a prime_list as an instance variable thus multiple threads will have its own prime_list. You can mark the prime_list static and the methods which access those also static. And within those methods the code must be inside of synchronized blocks.

This is not the best design. If I write from the beginning I won't use this design but it will work for you.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;  
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class CheckThread  implements Runnable{

private final GenerateThread generated;
private static ArrayList<Primes> prime_list = new ArrayList();
//private CopyOnWriteArrayList<Primes> prime_list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList();
private final String threadName;
private boolean alive = true;
private boolean toggle = true;
private Date timeFetched;
private Date timeFound;
private Primes currentPrime;

// START: FOR PANEL LAYOUT //
JPanel genPanel = new JPanel();

JPanel lastPane = new JPanel();
JLabel lastOutput = new JLabel();

JPanel queuePane = new JPanel();
JLabel queueOutput = new JLabel();

JLabel headLabel = new JLabel("Generate Thread");
JLabel lastLabel = new JLabel("Last");
JLabel queueLabel = new JLabel("In Work");

JButton pauseButton = new JButton("Pause");
JButton terminateButton = new JButton("Terminate");
// END: FOR PANEL LAYOUT //

CheckThread(GenerateThread gen, String name, int priority)
{
    generated = gen;
    threadName = name;
    headLabel.setText(name);
    System.out.println("Creating | " + name);

    if(priority == 0)
    {
       System.out.println(name + " Is writing thread");
        final Timer t = new Timer(10000, new writeToFileTimer());
        t.start();
    }
}

public JPanel createPanel()
{
   lastPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
   lastPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200,100));
   queuePane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));


   terminateButton.addActionListener(new terminateListener());

   pauseButton.addActionListener(new pauseListener());

   lastPane.add(lastOutput);
   queuePane.add(queueOutput);

   genPanel.add(headLabel);
   genPanel.add(lastLabel);
   genPanel.add(lastPane);
   genPanel.add(queueLabel);
   genPanel.add(queuePane);
   genPanel.add(pauseButton);
   genPanel.add(terminateButton);

   lastOutput.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
   return genPanel;
}
 class writeToFileTimer implements ActionListener
 {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
       try{ writeToFile();}catch (InterruptedException e) { System.out.println("WTF");}
    }
 }

@Override
public void run() 
{
    while(alive)
    {
        try 
        {
            if(toggle)
            {
                PrimeCandidate recieved = new PrimeCandidate(generated.getFromArrayList());
                timeFetched = new Date();
                //queueOutput.setText(recieved.getCandidate().toString());
                if(TestForPrime.isPrime(recieved.getCandidate()))
                {
                    lastOutput.setText(recieved.getCandidate().toString());
                    timeFound = new Date();
                    String temp = "" + prime_list.size();
                    queueOutput.setText(temp);
                    addToArrayList(new Primes(recieved.getCandidate(),recieved.getTimeStamp(), timeFetched));
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}

class terminateListener implements ActionListener
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    { 
        terminateButton.setEnabled(false);
        pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
        alive = false;
    }
}

class pauseListener implements ActionListener
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    { 
        if(toggle)
            pauseButton.setText("Start");
        if(!toggle)
            pauseButton.setText("Pause");
        toggle = !toggle;
    }
}

// ADDS NEW ITEM TO ARRAYLIST AND NOTIFYS ALL THREADS DEPENDENT ON ARRAYLIST 
public static void addToArrayList(Primes primeFound)
{
   synchronized(prime_list) { // Added this
       prime_list.add(primeFound);
   }
}

// USED BY THE OTHER THREADS TO GET ITEMS FROM THE ARRAY LIST, THREADS DELETE
// THE VARIABLE THAT THEY GRAB, ESSENTIALLY CUTTING THE ARRAY LIST DOWN EVERY
// TIME
public static void writeToFile() throws InterruptedException
{
    synchronized(prime_list) { // Added this
    try 
    {
        File statText = new File("prime_numbers.txt");

        FileOutputStream is = new FileOutputStream(statText);

        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(is);    

        Writer writ = new BufferedWriter(osw);
        for(int i=0;i<prime_list.size();i++) {
            writ.append(prime_list.get(i));
        }
        prime_list.clear();
        writ.close();
        headLabel.setText(threadName);

    } catch (IOException e) {System.err.println(" failed to write to Test.txt");}
    }
}   
}
```